# laravel Eloquent: Relationships get third part relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

iam working in journal project and i have 3 main table related 
Volumes->issues->articles

volume has many issue **but** issue has one volume 
issues has many articles **but** article has one issue

all working fine but i have 1 tricky step

i want to get volume name when view all articles. i want view the following when retrieving articles

```
article name | vol name/issue name
```

i success to get issue name as i have relation between **article module** and **issue module** but i dont know how to get volume name inside for-each articles

```
<tr>
     <th>Title</th>
     <th>Vol/Issue</th>
</tr>
@foreach($articles as $article)
  <td>{{ $article->title }}
  <td>{{ ??? }} / {{$article->issue->name}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: How about `$article->issue->volume->name` ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the belongs to relations set up in each model to act as the reverse of your has many relations:

```
class Article extends Model
{
    public function issue()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Issue::class);
    }
}

class Issue extends Model
{
    public function volume()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Volume::class);
    }
}
```

You should be able to eager load the `issue` relation and the `issue`'s `volume` relation when retrieving your articles, like this:

```
$articles = Article::with(['issue', 'issue.volume'])->get();
```

and in your view (Assuming you use the `name` attribute):

```
{{ $article->issue->volume->name }}
```

For more information regarding this, look up "Nested Eager Loading" in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)